# Incorrect font of the greek letters while using xepersian

Tags: greek, xepersian

I want to use greek letters in the text with Helvetica font. When I compile the my code in the English version, I get to correct form. I mean, when I compile the following code

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
%\usepackage{xepersian}
%\settextfont{Yas}


\begin{document}
\textPsi 

\textlambda
\end{document}
```

I get the results as I want

[image]

But when I enable `xepersian` package,

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}


\begin{document}
\textPsi 

\textlambda
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

which is not what I want. How can I have the first case while I'm using `xepersian` package?

Comment: I don't know `xepersian`, but looks like it loads a specific font for those characters. Maybe look at the doc package and look which fonts are loaded. You can then add your proper `set*font` after loading this package

Comment: The glyphs in your first example are not Helvetica, and the Helvetica clone on CTAN does not cover Greek. You could use GFS Neohellenic from the Greek Font Society. You could write `\(\lambda\)`, etc., if you just need individual Greek symbols instead of words. If you do, you might load a package such as `babel` or `polyglossia` that supports the Greek language.

Comment: If you want those specific symbols, they are actually `cbgreek`.

Comment: Dear @Davislor when I use `cbgreek` option of the `textgreek` package, nothing happens.

Comment: @AYBRXQD I don’t use `xepersian` myself, but, A: does loading your Greek font after `xepersian` work? B: Can you use `babel` instead and enter Persian into your editor in Unicode? C: Can you use the math-mode symbols, or do you need Greek words?

Comment: Dear @Davislor, I need to use `xepersian`. Furthermore, using the greek font after `xepersian` did not work out.

Comment: Since you only need greek letters, consider using `$\Psi$` instead of `\textPsi`. This change might be enough to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you’re trying to combine modern fonts with legacy 7-bit font encodings from the 1980s in such a way that you were never actually displaying Greek letters in Helvetica at all.  Since `xepersian` loads `fontspec`, you should just load a modern Greek font.  You should also display left-to-right text inside the `\lr` command or the `latin` environment when using `xepersian`.

The one you liked was from `cbgreek`, and the glyphs in Computer Modern Unicode are based on that.  Select `Script=Greek` to get glyphs that look like the modern Greek language, and `Script=Default` to get glyphs that look like the math symbols in classic TeX.

If you want something that matches the text fonts better, Arial is a look-alike of Helvetica that (unlike TeX Gyre Heros) contains Greek letters, or you might try a free font from the Greek Font Society, such as GFS Neohellenic.

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\tracinglostchars=2 % Warn you if a character is missing!
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry} % Solely to format the MWE on TeX.SX.
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\settextfont{XB Yas}
\setlatintextfont{Arial}
\setlatinsansfont{Arial}
\deflatinfont\Greekfont[Script=Greek]{CMU Serif}

\DeclareTextFontCommand\textgreek{\Greekfont}

\newcommand\textPsi{Ψ}
\newcommand\textlambda{λ}

\begin{document}
\begin{latin}
Some text.  \textPsi \textlambda

Greek font: \textgreek{\textPsi \textlambda}
\end{latin}

\rl{خشایارشا} \lr{\textgreek{Ξέρξης} Xerxes}
\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

If you needed a `greek` environment like the one in `polyglossia`, for full paragraphs, you would define that with

```
\newenvironment{greek}{\begin{latin}\Greekfont}{\end{latin}}
```

Although at that point you would really want to load a package that supports hyphenation patterns.

Unfortunately, `fontspec` does not declare macros such as `\textAlpha` and `\textbeta`.  Here, I declare them in the preamble, but if you also load `unicode-math`, that package declares them as `\mupAlpha`, `\mupbeta`, etc.

Finally, if you only need Greek symbols and not words, you could load the math font you like and use `\(\Psi \lambda\)` in math mode.